# What kind of Relation do I use? Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, relation, pfrelation

I'm new to Parse and I have watched several tutorials from Parse.com about the Parse-Relation. But I just can't figure it out!

Let's say I'm making an app for a School.

- We have classes with students.
- And students can be in different classes.
- And every class has tasks.
- And every student in that specific class can say if he did it or not!

**For example:** 
John and Elly are sitting in Class "1". 
In Class "1", there are the following tasks: Clean up, make homework, reset the computer etc.. 
John did clean up, did made his homework but he didn't reset the computer. 
Elly did clean up, did not made here homework but she did reset the computer.

What is the best relation here? What kind of tables should I create in Parse database? And how do I print out all the answers for the tasks that had to be done, and who did it or not?

I hope I explained it well!

***I'm using iOS***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: @Saurabh, do you have any idea where I can post this question else where? Thank you :)

Comment: I disagree that it is not related to programming, but the question is far too broad. You should try solving it and then ask for help on more specific topics. You can use PFRelation or pointers. What you are essentially asking is how to structure your database schema. Have a look at the parse.com tutorial for Anypic and see if you can use the concept of activities in your case. Then, if you run into problems on smaller areas, ask away in here :-)